# Must use non-blocking assignment in a procedural block in System Verilog?

Tags: variable-assignment, nonblocking, system-verilog

I've met a situation where I think I have to use blocking assignment in a `@(posedge clk)` block. The snippet below is from a tsetbench. I want to input the data to a DUT through the testbench. input_intf is the name of an interface and wcb is a clocking block synchronizing to wclk.

```
   @(posedge input_intf.wclk)
    begin
      input_intf.winc = 1;
      input_intf.wcb.wdata = 8'd7;
      input_intf.winc = 0;
    end
```

I want to do the following: after the positive clock edge, inc=1 and data reading is enabled. After data is read, let inc=0. I guess maybe winc signal has no need to be synchronous with wclk? If it's the case then the snippet should be like following.

```
input_intf.winc = 1;

@(posedge input_intf.wclk)
   input_intf.wcb.wdata <= 8'd7;

input_intf.winc = 0;
```

So is it true that we must use non-blocking assignment in a procedural block? When learning Verilog, I was told it's true.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement `input_intf.wcb.wdata = 8'd7;` is illegal. You do not use blocking or non-blocking assignments to drive *clocking block outputs*. See **14.16.1 Drives and non-blocking assignments** in the [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) LRM. For other non-clocking block variables inside your interface, you use the same rules that you learned with Verilog: use non-blocking assignments to write to variables that are synchronous to a clock, and will be read by other procedural blocks on the same clock edge. That is how you avoid races.

The use of clocking blocks is generally an all or nothing approach. you should not be mixing writing to clocking block and non-clocking variables in the same procedure, and you should only be using the clocking block event to synchronize your code.

```
@(input_intf.wcb) // do not use posedge of any signal here.
   input_intf.wcb.wdata <= 8'd7;
```

There are exceptions to these rules, of course, but I would make sure you know exactly how clocking blocks work before going there.

Comment: I'm quite new to SV. I think clocking block is to indicate that the signals inside one clocking block are syn to the clock event. But I don't know how clocking blocks work in more detail.

Comment: Can I think @(input_inf.wcb) is equal to @(posedge input_intf.wclk) but the former is better? Or @(posedge input_intf.wclk) is not correct.

Comment: Also, I have found it's illegal to use nonblocking assignment to assign a clocking block output to an automatic variable in a procedural block. I don't know the reason why. Maybe that's also because I don't know how clocking block works

Comment: @(input_inf.wcb) is not exactly the same as @(posedge input_intf.wclk) when interacting with clocking block inputs or outputs. There is an example in section 14.13 of the 1800-2012 LRM that explains the difference.

Comment: You are not allowed to use non-blocking assignments to write to automatic variables regardless of the expression in the right-hand-side. It has nothing to do with clocking blocks.

Comment: Interestingly, what I read from 15.9 of LRM 3.1a is @(input_intf.wcb) is equivalent to @(posedge input_intf.wclk). I guess maybe we are using different versions of LRM since I found "14.16.1 Drives and non-blocking assignments" is actually 15.14.1 in LRM 3.1a

Comment: Throw away your SV3.1a LRM - released when no one had a working SV simulator and is over 10 years old. Get the [latest version](http://go.mentor.com/get-1800).